# How prove $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{w_{j}}{1-p_{j}}\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{w_{j}}{1+p_{j}}\le \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{w_{j}}{1-p^2_{j}}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality

let $w_{j}\ge 0,j=1,2,3,\cdots,n,n\ge 2$,and such $$w_{1}+w_{2}+\cdots+w_{n}=1$$
for any $p_{j}\in[0,1),j=1,2,3,\cdots,n)$,have 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{w_{j}}{1-p_{j}}\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{w_{j}}{1+p_{j}}\le
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{w_{j}}{1-p^2_{j}}\right)^2$$

this problem is from Shang hai High school
in china test.maybe this problem can use integral inequality to solve it? or others.Thank you

Comment: What age is middle school? My first guess would be the Cauchy Schwarz inequality for some useful scalar product .. hm..

Comment: Hello,about $15-16$ age.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is not usefull to this problem

Answer (score 6):

This is simply AM-GM:

$$\sum \frac{w_j}{1 - p_j} \cdot \sum \frac{w_j}{1 + p_j} \le \left( \frac{\sum \frac{w_j}{1 - p_j} + \sum \frac{w_j}{1 + p_j}}{2} \right)^2 = \left(\sum \frac{w_j}{1 - p_j^2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Oh,I forgot,+1,but this condition is not usefull,I ask my student,maybe he give problem have some mistake

Comment: @math110: Yeah, We don't need to use anything else except $w_j \ge 0$ and $p_j \in [0,1)$.

Comment: Very nice. The hard bit is seeing the right equality.

Comment: That is easy to solve once one knows the trick. Did you knew a similiar trick before?

Comment: @mvw: I was thinking about using partial fractions at the right hand side and expanding the square to see what comes out, when I saw that it's just AM-GM.

Comment: @J.J. How did you get the equality from?

Comment: @Jika: The equality is partial fractions term-by-term: $\frac{1}{1 - p_j} + \frac{1}{1 + p_j} = \frac{1 - p_j + 1 + p_j}{(1 - p_j)(1 + p_j)} = \frac{2}{1 - p_j^2}$

Comment: @J.J. Ah Ok. I get it. Thank you very much $(+1)$. I was wrong because I developed $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$